# No module name django.core.wsgi apache2+ubuntu+mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, hosting, mod-wsgi

I have set up my wsgipythonpath and daemonprocess but the error log shows the above error no module named django.core.wsgi, i am sharing my conf, what could be the error, and how can i check if apache can acess my django installation or not. **I am able to host with same config on my local system but not on a remote server**

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/env_mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName  localhost
   DocumentRoot /home/unixadmin/PBpy

   WSGIScriptAlias / /home/unixadmin/PBpy/PBpy/wsgi.py

   WSGIDaemonProcess PBpy python-path=/home/env_mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages

   ErrorLog /home/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   <Directory "/home/unixadmin/PBpy">
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `WSGIDaemonProcess`

```
WSGIDaemonProcess <env> python-path=<path to project code> python-home=<path to env>
```

hope this is helpful.

Comment: sorry, it does not help, i am able to host using apache with the same above config on my local system but i dont know why  when i try on the sever it gives me such errors.  any further help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out about the mod_wsgi configuration.

1 - You use `WSGIDaemonProcess` but don't use `WSGIProcessGroup`, or the `application-group` option to `WSGIScriptAlias`, to delegate the WSGI application to run in the daemon process group.

2 - You don't use the recommended way of setting up a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi. See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

A further possible issue since you are trying to use a Python virtual environment is whether your mod_wsgi is even compiled for Python 2.7, and specifically the same Python installation. Was your Python virtual environment created using the system Python 2.7 installation, on the same target system?

Other odd things or sources of problems are:

1 - `ServerName` shouldn't be set to `localhost`. Things would only still work if that happened to be the first `VirtualHost` Apache finds.

2 - Home directories are often not accessible to user that your code is run as under Apache, so it may not even be able to see the Python packages.

Comment: What are the required permission should i give to the python packages as I am able to switch to root in my ubuntu machine?

Comment: Did you fix everything else first and ensure your mod_wsgi is compiled for same Python installation being used? Use checks in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use to ensure that correct Python virtual environment is being used and that ``sys.path`` constructed correctly. Directories should be ``o+rx`` and files ``o+r`` at least. If you don't understand what that means read https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod